# Line: 1: Qt Quick emulation layer crashed

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I created an empty QT Quick Application. my compiler is MinGW 64.
My project has main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

but when I want to see its UI in designer it gives me an error:
Line: 1: Qt Quick emulation layer crashed.

I change User fallback QML emulation layer to "C:\Qt\Qt5.14.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin" but it does not work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is looks like Qt Creator/Designer bug. The issues returns from time to time. See it [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-14031) for example. As I remember once it was a problem that `QML_IMPORT_PATH` was incorrectly rewritten. I would open a tick in the Qt bug tracker.

Comment: @folibis Any fixes? I jus installed qt for first time and got the same error.

Comment: Quite frustrating... was just looking to try out Qt as well and can't find a fix for this bug anywhere...

Comment: @mohammad-reza-kashi did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: For me the issue began after switching to Qt6.1

Comment: According to [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/QtFramework/comments/mw9mz9/qt_quick_emulation_layer_crashed_line_1/gvjqcgd?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) we need to wait until Qt Designer gets updated to Qt6

Answer (score -1):

I had the same misbehaviour with my fresh **Qt Creator** installation on **Ubuntu 20.04** with **Qt6**.

I solved my specific misbehaviour with the installation and usage of Qt5.12. In the Qt Quick Settings I chose the new installed Qt5.12 installation. [image]